# Is any RDP client can be used in Ubuntu 14.04 that can access Windows Server 2012?

Tags: 14.04, server, windows, remote-desktop

I want to access Windows Server 2012 from Ubuntu 14.04 through RDP, but I can't find a software that can be used to access Win2012. There uesed to be a software called `Remmina`, it can connect to Win2012, however it just show white screen all the time. So can anyone give me a client can be used to access to Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by reinstalling the latest version of `Remmina`.